# Question about cartesian product in a proof of measurability of a mapping

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

In a proof of the following result

> Let $(E_1, \mathcal{E}_1), ..., (E_n,\mathcal{E}_n)$ be measurable spaces. For all $k\in[1,n]$ the mapping $\pi_k : \Pi_{i=1}^{n}E_i\to E_k$ $\pi_k(x_1, ..., x_n) = x_k$ is measurable.

The proof start by considering $A\in\mathcal{E}_k$ and then it is written that

$
\pi_k^{-1}(A) = \left(\Pi_{i=1}^{k-1}E_i\right)\times A\times\left(\Pi_{i=k+1}^{n}E_i\right)\in\Pi_{i=1}^{n}\mathcal{E}_i
$

However from what I have understood, $\Pi_{i=1}^{n}\mathcal{E}_i$ is a sigma algebra on $\Pi_{i=1}^{n}E_i$ whereas $\pi_k^{-1}(A)$ is of the form

$
((x_1,...,x_{k-1}), x_k, (x_{k+1}, ..., x_n))
$

and not of the form of $(x_1, ..., x_n)$ which is not the same object. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Strictly speaking you are right, but in this context this abuse of notation is harmless.

Comment: @AnneBauval I don't understand why $\pi_k^{-1}(A)$ is not a subset of $\Pi_i E_i$ and I claim that elements of $\pi_k^{-1}(A)$  are indeed of the form $(x_1,...,x_{k_1},x_k,x_{k+1},...,x_n)$ for $x_k \in A$.

Comment: @blamethelag We all agree on that. Whence the question of the OP, who was worried to read that $\pi_k^{-1}(A)$ is a subset of $\left(\Pi_{i=1}^{k-1}E_i\right)\times E_k\times\left(\Pi_{i=k+1}^{n}E_i\right)$ i.e. that its elements were of the form $
((x_1,...,x_{k-1}), x_k, (x_{k+1}, ..., x_n))
.$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for your comment !

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you! I indeed never thought about that